# Converte circle coordinates in to degree values in gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot

I have a data file with 3 columns: The first 2 are coordinates of a circle, the 3. are results . How can I convert this x-y-coordinates into a range of degree (range of the x-axis: 0 - 360). I want to show results in a XY-plot. I don't want to create a further column in my data file, I want to convert the values directly with gnuplot. Is this possible?

Comment: Please post some sample data and explain what you are trying to do.  As it is, this is very difficult to understand.

Comment: the coordinates are the cartesian coordinates of a cylinder surface. the result values are the roughness of the surface. I want to show the roughness from 0 to 360 peripheral degree in different vertical sections. Y-axis=result values, x-axis= peripheral degree (from 0 to 360)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just remember your high school geometry and how to convert Cartesian coordinates to polar coordinates.  Suppose you have a Cartesian coordinate (*x*, *y*).  Draw a line between this point and the origin.  The angle *θ* between this line and the *x*-axis is related by tan *θ* = *y*/*x* and the distance *r* from the origin is sqrt(*x*<sup>2</sup> + *y*<sup>2</sup>).

So your angle *θ* is just the arc tangent (inverse tangent) of *y*/*x*.  In gnuplot, this is the `atan()` function.  I'd write something like this:

```
set angles degrees
plot 'infile.dat' using (atan($2/$1)):3 with points
```

where column 3 is your "result" (the roughness) and columns 1 and 2 are your Cartesian coordinates.  It uses the calculated *θ* value for the horizontal plotted axis and the roughness for the vertical plotted axis.

The `set angles` command lets you set the unit used by `atan()` to degrees or radians.  Since you specified a range of 0-360, it is `set angles degrees`.

It will plot the points in the order as they appear in the file.  Notice that depending on the order of points in your data file, the order of the points after this calculation may no longer be visually sequential, so this example uses `with points`.